# Right and left floating of odd and even elements

Tags: html, css, css-float

Here's the problem. I got simple html template:

```
<div class="wrapper"><div class="inside">

    <div class="left"><p>Lorem ipsum...</p></div>
    <aside><p>Lorem ipsum...</p></aside>
    <div class="left"><p>Lorem ipsum...</p></div>
    <aside><p>Lorem ipsum...</p></aside>
    <div class="left"><p>Lorem ipsum...</p></div>
    <aside><p>Lorem ipsum...</p></aside>

</div></div>
```

And simple CSS:

```
div.wrapper {width:1020px;margin:0 auto;}
div.wrapper .inside {padding: 10px;}
div.left {width:700px;background:#EEE;float:left;border-top:1px solid #000; clear: left;}
aside {width:300px;background:#CCC;float:right;border-top:1px solid #000; clear: right;}
```

I want all divs to be on the left side of the page, one after another, without any spacing and all asides on the righ side. And there it is. No matter how high the content of asides is the divs are working fine. But if the content of any div is too hight I'm getting empty space between asides, like there was something like clear:both along with this div.

Example:

[image]

I want it to always look like this, no empty spaces whatsoever: [image]

I cannot change html (divs&asides order), I can change only CSS. I can use html5 and css3.

http://jsfiddle.net/HRp2H/

Comment: Yeah, floats won't work for you because of the HTML structure. You'll need a different solution. Is JavaScript (jQuery) an option?

Comment: You cant change html at all or only the order ?

Comment: Instead of floating all of the individual elements you'd be better off having a left and right wrapper and placing the elements within the wrappers. SO only those two wrappers are floated and not all the DIVs and Asides.

Comment: "I cannot change html (divs&asides order)..."

Comment: I cannot change html structrure at all. It must be div/aside/div/aside...

Comment: @Ecnelis: yes, that covers the "can you change the order" question, are you able to add, or amend, element `id`s or classes? Because this can't be done with CSS.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could add a CSS gradient to simulate full columns:

http://jsfiddle.net/HRp2H/5

```
div.wrapper {
    width:400px;
    margin:0 auto;
    padding: 10px;
}
div.wrapper .inside {
    background: -moz-linear-gradient(left, #eee 250px, #ccc 250px);
    overflow: auto;
}
div.left {
    width:250px;
    float:left;
    border-top:1px solid #000;
    clear: left;
}
aside {
    width:150px;
    float:right;
    border-top:1px solid #000;
    clear: right;
}
```

Here I've moved the padding that you had on .inside to its child elements: http://jsfiddle.net/HRp2H/3

UPDATE: Here's how you might do it using jQuery. I'd use my earlier answer as a fallback.

http://jsfiddle.net/HRp2H/7/

```
.leftCol, .rightCol {float: left;}
.leftCol .left, .rightCol aside {display: block}
div.left {
    display: none;
    ...
}
aside {
    display: none;
    ..
}

var myLefts = $('.inside').clone().find('aside').remove().end().html();
var myAsides = $('.inside').clone().find('.left').remove().end().html();

$('.wrapper .inside').html('');

$('.wrapper .inside').append('<div class="leftCol" />');
$('.wrapper .leftCol').append(myLefts);

$('.wrapper .inside').append('<div class="rightCol" />');
$('.wrapper .rightCol').append(myAsides);
```

Comment: The "white" is not a problem. ;) The empty space is.

Comment: Sorry. If that's the case, you're out of luck. You didn't answer my earlier question about JavaScript, though.

Comment: Thank you, looks nice! But I'm still looking for CSS solution. The site is going to be big and I'm afraid jQuery will cause new problems...

Comment: Good luck, but as you've been told it's probably not possible. Also, I'd hate to work on a big site *without* jQuery.

Comment: I am of course using jQuery, I just don't want to use it in this case. :) Either way it all ended up using jQ. Thank you for help!

Answer (score 0):

Check this fiddle out:

http://jsfiddle.net/HRp2H/4/

It utilises a css hack to make floating columns the same height:

```
margin-bottom: -500px;
padding-bottom: 500px;
overflow: hidden;
```

and then

```
overflow: hidden;
```

on the main div

Comment: Not bad! The padding is throwing it off by 10px, but this works, too.

Comment: It is working on "white" space, but I'm looking to get rid of any empty space. Sorry for previous confusion.

Answer (score 0):

Try using [JQuery masonry](http://masonry.desandro.com/). It can stack all of your `DIV` blocks neatly on top of each other